# Pandas - EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file when reading stock .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let me first start by saying I have gone through and done my due diligence trying to find a solution based on questions previously asked on the web.

I've run into an odd bug in my code that I really cannot explain...
So far my code executes the following:

1. take stock symbols and write OHLC data to a CSV file
2. loop through the directory that contains the CSV files and use that data to calculate technical indicators
3. add the technical indicator data to the same CSV file

   So the bug is that it executes everything perfectly (99 stocks) EXCEPT for ZM.csv (Zoom). The error that it prints is"

   > pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file.

So to troubleshoot I copied and pasted the data from ZM.csv into a CSV that I know ran fine (I used AAPL) and it actually executed fine. Next, I took the working data from `AAPL.csv`, pasted it into `ZM.csv` and ran it again. It throws the same error. I also tried renaming the file to ZMI (randomly) and it worked.

This led me to believe that for some unknown reason that the FILENAME is the root issue. The part where I first create the CSV files, I changed the name of the file to be {symbol}1.csv, {symbol}_.csv, and {symbol}I.csv to no avail. Lastly, I combined the two files together and did not mess with anything else. It worked. Does anyone know why?

The flow is to first run `bars.py`, check the `data/ohlc/` directory CSV files (should only have the OHLC data), run `technical_analysis.py`, and then check the CSV files again (now with technical indicators).

#### [bar.py]

```
    from config import *
    from datetime import datetime
    import requests, json

    holdings = open('data/qqq.csv').readlines()

    symbols_list = [holding.split(',')[2].strip() for holding in holdings][1:]
    symbols = ','.join(symbols_list)

    minute_bars_url = '{}/1Min?symbols={}&limit=100'.format(BARS_URL, symbols)
    r = requests.get(minute_bars_url, headers=HEADERS)

    ohlc_data = r.json()

    for symbol in ohlc_data:
        filename = 'data/ohlc/{}.csv'.format(symbol)
        f = open(filename, 'w+')
        f.write('Timestamp,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\n')
        for bar in ohlc_data[symbol]:
            t = datetime.fromtimestamp(bar['t'])
            timestamp = t.strftime('%I:%M:%S%p-%Z%Y-%m-%d')
            line = '{},{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(timestamp, bar['o'], bar['h'],                                                 
                                                 bar['l'], bar['c'], bar['v'])
            f.write(line)
```

The variables symbols_list and symbols print as follows:

```
symbols_list = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'GOOGL', 'GOOG', 'TSLA', 'NVDA', 'PYPL', 'ADBE', 'INTC', 'NFLX', 'CMCSA', 'PEP', 'COST', 'CSCO', 'AVGO', 'QCOM', 'TMUS', 'AMGN', 'TXN', 'CHTR', 'SBUX', 'ZM', 'AMD', 'INTU', 'ISRG', 'MDLZ', 'JD', 'GILD', 'BKNGLD', 'BKNG', 'FISV', 'MELI', 'ATVI', 'ADP', 'CSX', 'REGN', 'MU', 'AMAT', 'ADSK', 'VRTX', 'LRCX', 'ILMN', 'ADI', 'BIIB', 'MNST', 'EXC', 'KDP', 'LULU', 'DOCU', 'WDAY', 'CTSH', 'KHC', 'NXPI', 'BIDU', 'XEL', 'DXCM', 'EBAY', 'EA', 'ID', 'SNPS',XX', 'CTAS', 'SNPS', 'ORLY', 'SGEN', 'SPLK', 'ROST', 'WBA', 'KLAC', 'NTES', 'PCAR', 'CDNS', 'MAR', 'VRSK', 'PAYX', 'ASML', 'ANSS', 'MCHP', 'XLNX', 'MRNA', 'CPRT', 'ALGN', 'PDD', 'ALXN', 'SIRI', 'FAST', 'SWKS', 'VRSN', 'DLTR', 'CE 'TTWO', 'RN', 'MXIM', 'INCY', 'TTWO', 'CDW', 'CHKP', 'CTXS', 'TCOM', 'BMRN', 'ULTA', 'EXPE', 'FOXA', 'LBTYK', 'FOX', 'LBTYA']
symbols = AAPL,MSFT,AMZN,FB,GOOGL,GOOG,TSLA,NVDA,PYPL,ADBE,INTC,NFLX,CMCSA,PEP,COST,CSCO,AVGO,QCOM,TMUS,AMGN,TXN,CHTR,SBUX,ZM,AMD,INTU,ISRG,MDLZ,JD,GILD,BKNG,FISV,MELI,ATVI,ADP,CSX,REGN,MU,AMAT,ADSK,VRTX,LRCX,ILMN,ADI,BIIB,MNST,EXC,KDP,LULU,DOCU,WDAU,DOCU,WDAY,CTSH,KHC,NXPI,BIDU,XEL,DXCM,EBAY,EA,IDXX,CTAS,SNPS,ORLY,SGEN,SPLK,ROST,WBA,KLAC,NTES,PCAR,CDNS,MAR,VRSK,PAYX,ASML,ANSS,MCHP,XLNX,MRNA,CPRT,ALGN,PDD,ALXN,SIRI,FAST,SWKS,VRSN,DLTR,CERN,MXIM,INCY,TTWO,CDW,CHKP,CTXS,TCOM,EXPE,FOXA,BMRN,ULTA,EXPE,FOXA,LBTYK,FOX,LBTYA
```

So ZM is not listed last.

#### [technical_analysis.py]

```
    import btalib
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    from bars import ohlc_data
    from bars import symbols_list as symbols

    for symbol in symbols:
        try:
            file_path = f'data/ohlc/{symbol}.csv'
            dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path,
                                parse_dates=True,
                                index_col='Timestamp')

            sma6 = btalib.sma(dataframe, period=6)
            sma10 = btalib.sma(dataframe, period=10)
            rsi = btalib.rsi(dataframe)
            macd = btalib.macd(dataframe)

            dataframe['SMA-6'] = sma6.df
            dataframe['SMA-10'] = sma10.df
            dataframe['RSI'] = rsi.df
            dataframe['MACD'] = macd.df['macd']
            dataframe['Signal'] = macd.df['signal']
            dataframe['Histogram'] = macd.df['histogram']

            f = open(file_path, 'w+')
            dataframe.to_csv(file_path, sep=',', index=True)
        except:
            print(f'{symbol} is not writing the technical data.')
```

Comment: is `ZM` the last item in `data/qqq.csv`? If you add a bogus symol at the end, does ZM read successfully?

Comment: Please make sure to tag pandas issues [tag:pandas] so they get a quick response from people watching that tag. Also, this one is about `pd.read_csv()`; please remove the lines of code after the `pd.read_csv` and reduce your code to [MCVE], examples on SO are required to be Minimal.

Comment: If the `pd.read_csv()` fails on 'ZM.csv', then just chop your example down to that, and show us its first few lines, perhaps the header or data are malformed. Absolute minimal lines of code to reproduce that. Also, a debugging tip is you can do a Python `assert` after `read_csv` that the dataframe or its columns have the expected number of rows/columns; that will cause an immediate exception if they don't.

Comment: *"Next, I renamed the file to ZMI (randomly) and it works... This leads me to believe that for some unknown reason that the FILENAME is the root issue."* Not exactly. It does prove that your code is misreading the (alphabetically) last file. The actual filename itself probably doesn't matter (you could shuffle them), only the order.

Comment: For some reason combining the bars.py and technical_analysis.py files together solves this issue... If anyone knows why I would be very curious what the cause of the issue was.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can [accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can also upvote answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error might be since 'ZM' is the last symbol in `holdings`, it contains some whitespace, due to in `[bar.py]` you created `holdings` the following way (instead of just the normal `pd.read_csv`):

```
holdings = open('data/qqq.csv').readlines()

symbols_list = [holding.split(',')[2].strip() for holding in holdings][1:]
symbols = ','.join(symbols_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably reduce the code more to get a minimally viable example. I suspect there is something funny in the `qqq.csv` file and the split/strip code that makes the last entry not quite what you want.

Hopefully, that'll be clear printing the variable values as below.

with `data/qqq.csv` like

```
xname,yname,symbol
xxx,yyy,ZM
```

and py example

```
def write_OHLC(fname):
    "write example data to a file"
    f = open(fname, 'w+')
    f.write('Timestamp,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\n')
    # IRL, would parse json and spitout meaningful values
    f.write('2020-10-13 16:30,1,10,5,100\n')


def all_symbols():
    "get list of all symbols from qqq.csv"
    holdings = open('data/qqq.csv').readlines()
    symbols_list = [holding.split(',')[2].strip() for holding in holdings][1:]
    return symbols_list

# issue saving/reading last(?) symbol
symbols = all_symbols()
print(symbols)
# check just zoom
zm_sym = symbols[-1]
fname = f'data/ohlc/{zm_sym}.csv'
# inspect
print(zm_sym)
print(fname)
# write and read back
write_OHLC(fname)
ZM = pd.read_csv(fname,
                 parse_dates=True,
                 index_col='Timestamp')
print(ZM)
```

Comment: For some reason combining the bars.py and technical_analysis.py files together solves this issue... Also, ZM was printed kind of in the middle of the list of symbols. That qqq.csv is not alphabetically organized. Thank you for your response! Would you happen to know why simply combining the files made a difference?

Comment: how did you previously import `technical_analysis.py`? It doesn't look like there is a function or class. variable scoping might have been weird

Comment: So I imported the symbols_list variable from the bar.py file to use in the loop in technical_analysis.py.

Comment: oh wow. i totally missed the `for symbol in symbols:` line in the second file! The indenting isn't correct there. That must be a formatting issue? otherwise you'd get an obvious "indendtationError"?

Comment: Yeah sorry this is my first post on stack overflow and it took me a while to figure the formatting out. I'll edit. But as far as the error goes, do you have any clue why executing the code in one file would solve the problem?

Comment: No idea :) I think there's another piece missing. You're calling these two files from another place, like a notebook? importing without scoping variables to a class or function can get hairy.  It'd make a great question on it's own. just needs to be reworked to follow  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So I just execute the files consecutively. So I run python bars.py then python technical_analysis.py in the command prompt. Thank you for the reference, I will check it out!